# Add a column to a dataframe with values based on another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column called Province and I need to add a new column  called Region. The value is based on the Province column. Here is the dataframe:

```
    Province 
 1  Alberta   
 2  Manitoba
 3  Ontario
 4  British Columbia
 5  Nova Scotia
 6  New Brunswick
 7  Quebec
```

Output:

```
   Province            Region
 1  Alberta             Prairies
 2  Manitoba            Prairies
 3  Ontario             Central
 4  British Columbia    Pacific
 5  Nova Scotia         East
 6  New Brunswick       East
 7  Quebec              East
```

I tried this code in R and it is not working.

```
Region <- as.character(Province) 

if (length(grep("British Comlumbia", Province)) > 0) { 
    return("Pacific") 
}
```

Comment: You have a list of Regions or you planning to do this one by one manually?

Comment: No I only have a list of Provinces and would like to create a list of Regions according to the other list. I tried d0ct0r code and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create vectors and do a step-wise replacement. This may not be an apt way but this will work.

```
Prairies <- c("Alberta","Manitoba")
Central <- c("Ontario")
Pacific <- c("British Colombia")
East <- c("Nova Scotia","New Brusnwick","Quebec")
#make a copy of the column province
df$Region <- as.vector(df[,1])
#one by one replace the items based on your vectors
df$Region <- replace(df$Region, df$Region%in%Prairies, "Prairies")
df$Region <- replace(df$Region, df$Region%in%Central, "Central")
df$Region <- replace(df$Region, df$Region%in%Pacific, "Pacific")
df$Region <- replace(df$Region, df$Region%in%East, "East")
```

Comment: Thanks d0ct0r, the code is working! Very much appreciated!